# Infinite while loop in python - with conflicting conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

my typo error led in the 'while loop' function led me to the following question

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def control_pressure():
    pressure = measure_pressure()
    while True:
        if pressure <= 500:
            break

        while pressure > 500 and pressure <= 700:
            run_standard_safeties()
            pressure = measure_pressure()

        while pressure > 100:                     # Here is the typo
            run_critical_safeties()
            pressure = measure_pressure()

    print("Wow! The system is safe...")

def measure_pressure():
    pressure = randint(450, 800)
    print(f"psi={pressure}", end="; ")
    return pressure

def run_standard_safeties():
    print("Running standard safeties...")
    sleep(0.2)

def run_critical_safeties():
    print("Running critical safeties...")
    sleep(0.7)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    control_pressure()
```

In the above, I made a typo and checked pressure > 100, while condition. But earlier in the first part of the function, it checked, while pressure <= 500, then break. So technically any value lesser than or equal to 500 should return True and break the function without reaching the pressure > 100 condition.

But this function continued without stopping. Why does it happen?

Thanks

Comment: You are getting confused between ```return``` and ```break```. ```return``` terminates the function but ```break``` only breaks the loop. All statements after the loop are then executed

Comment: If the outer `while` loop is not breaking, that only means `pressure` is always greater than 500, try printing `pressure` in the outer `while` loop.

Comment: No, already the code displays the pressure value through the code - print(f"psi={pressure}", end="; ") in the measure_pressure() function. But still it doesn't break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario is best described sequentially.

Any initial pressure greater than 500 will bypass the `break` and continue to the first inner loop. Since you're getting a random value `450..800` (a range of `350` - ranges here may be off by one but they're close enough so as not to matter), this has a probability of about `300/350` (the numerator comes from the `500..800` range) or 85%.

The first inner loop will then run as long as you're getting pressures in the range `500..700`, a probability of about `200/350`, or 57%.

At some point you'll exit that first inner loop and enter the second. And you *will* enter it because all values in the range `450..800`, that you can possibly get as a pressure, are greater than a hundred.

That means, of course, that you will also never *exit* that loop because no pressure you ever get after that point  will be a hundred or less, which is what's needed to exit the loop.

---

As an aside, you could actually avoid this loops-within-loops structure by realising that you to get the pressure every iteration of every loop, so that can be made common.

Assuming your typo was to use `100` where you meant `700` (as that marches with mutually exclusive ranges), that can be simplified to:

```py
def control_pressure():
    while True:
        pressure = measure_pressure()
        if pressure <= 500:
            print("Wow! The system is safe...")
            return

        if pressure <= 700:
            run_standard_safeties()
        else:
            run_critical_safeties()
```

Or, if you want to use the `:=` walrus operator<sup>(a)</sup> (available in Python 3.8+, I think), you could shorten it even further by getting and checking pressure as part of the `while` statement:

```py
def control_pressure():
    while (pressure := measure_pressure()) > 500:
        if pressure <= 700:
            run_standard_safeties()
        else:
            run_critical_safeties()
    print("Wow! The system is safe...")
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> So called because, if you rotate it 90° clockwise and squint, it looks like a walrus with its two eyes and two huge tusks.

[image]

It basically (in this case) lets you assign a value to a variable as part of checking said variable, so that the value is available for later checks as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the initial number is above 100 and above 500 it will enter  the second loop and never stop since it will always be above 100, since your are taking one at random from 450-800.

Comment: Imagine, random number is 460, which is True for the first condition pressure <= 500. Then the loop should break and exit and the only statement outside the loop is : print('"Wow! The system is safe..."). It should be printed after the loop exiting. Although, pressure > 100 is true with the number 460, the loop technically should not reach there, as the first condition is already met and it should break the loop there. However, the loop continues to run infinite

Comment: If the number is 460 the main loop should quit. I tried to recreate the error you are mentioning and couldn't, for `pressure=460` the main loop does break and the program finishes